# Count frequency of each word contained in column string values

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
        'value': ['red','red and blue','yellow','oak','oak wood']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value'])
```

I want :

```
id value   count
1  red     2
1  blue    1
1  yellow  1
2  oak     2
2  wood    1
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for pandas 0.25+ with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by lists created by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(value = df['value'].str.split())
         .explode('value')
         .groupby(['id','value'], sort=False)
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   id   value  count
0   1     red      2
1   1     and      1
2   1    blue      1
3   1  yellow      1
4   2     oak      2
5   2    wood      1
```

For lower pandas versions use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `expand=True` for `DataFrame`, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create columns from `MultiIndex Series` ands use same solution like above:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('id')['value']
         .str.split(expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='value')
         .groupby(['id','value'], sort=False)
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count')
         )
print (df1)
   id   value  count
0   1     red      2
1   1     and      1
2   1    blue      1
3   1  yellow      1
4   2     oak      2
5   2    wood      1
```

Comment: Thank you again! Your answer works perfectly for me as usual!